# Monitoring Ethereum Contracts for specific function calls - missing methods in ABI

Tags: contract-invocation, etherscan

I created a script to accept a contract address and watch that contract for specific "events." In this case, I want to check each time the Loot for Snail function is invoked on the [EvoSnails NFT contract.](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8a6e948a30ee8cb1391712710c1c59be553ab008)

As you can see in the transactions, the method has been called quite a few times and it shows on the contract tx list. However, when I try to run my script to check for this event, the event does not exist in the contract.

A snippet of my code, which checks the Contract ABI for it's events and functions is here:

```
async function getContractABI(contractAddress) {
    let opts = {
        url: `http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${contractAddress}&apikey=${etherscanApiKey}`,
        responseType: 'json'
    }

    try {
        let response = await got(opts);
        const contractABI = JSON.parse(response.body.result);

        return contractABI;
    }

    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

const getContractEvents = async (contractAddress) => {
    let contractABI = await getContractABI(contractAddress);
    
    let contractEvents = contractABI.map(i => {
// i.type would be event but it doesn't appear for event or 'function'
        if (i.type === 'event'){
            return i.name;
        }
    })
    var results = contractEvents.reduce((results, item) => {
        if (typeof item === 'string') results.push(item) // modify is a fictitious function that would apply some change to the items in the array
        return results;
    }, [])

    return results;
}

getContractEvents("0x8a6e948a30ee8cb1391712710c1c59be553ab008");
```

[image: This is the result from the script.]

As you can see, Loot for Snail is not here. How would I be able to monitor for this specific function when it is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract deployed at [0x8a6e948a30ee8cb1391712710c1c59be553ab008](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8a6e948a30ee8cb1391712710c1c59be553ab008#code) is the OpenZeppelin TransparentUpgradeableProxy proxy (the original implementation of your NFT contract is here: [0x9539EAC4e19d0627815b166330b83f9c931A9e88](https://etherscan.io/address/0x9539eac4e19d0627815b166330b83f9c931a9e88#code)

It means that you should listen to transaction to/from the **proxy** (0x8a6e) using the abi from the **original** contract (0x9539).

Check the Openzepellin post for additional details : https://blog.openzeppelin.com/the-transparent-proxy-pattern/

Comment: Thank you for the help. How were you able to find that it was using a proxy?

Comment: If you check on etherscan the 0x8a6e address, you can see the contract name (TransparentUpgradeableProxy) as well as the "Read as Proxy" tab (https://etherscan.io/address/0x8a6e948a30ee8cb1391712710c1c59be553ab008#readProxyContract) where you'll find the address of the original/target contract.